# Default copy constructor and assignment for class with move constructor and assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
};
```

AFAIK, compiler provides default copy constructor and assignment operators, which assign every member of other instance to the current instance. Now I add move constructor and assignment:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    Test(Test&& other);
    Test& operator=(Test&& other);
};
```

Does this class still contain compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operators, or I need to implement them?

**Edit**. This is my test:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(){}

    Test(Test&& other){}
    Test& operator=(Test&& other)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    int n;
    char str[STR_SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    t1.n = 2;
    strcpy(t1.str, "12345");

    Test t2(t1);

    Test t3;
    t3 = t1;

    cout << t2.n << " " << t2.str << " " << t3.n << " " << t3.str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints `2 12345 2 12345`. Compiler: VC++ 2010. According to this test, copy constructor and assignment are still here. Is this standard behavior, can I be sure that this will work on every C++ compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From **12.8-7 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared *implicitly*. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor...

From **12.8-18**

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor...

According to this, since you have declared a move constructor *and* a move assignment operator, but no copy assignment operator, copy constructor or destructor, you do **not** get the implicitly generated copy constructor or assignment operator. The compiler gives you their *declarations*, but they are declared as `deleted`.

Here is a simplified version of your example:

```
struct Test
{
public:
    Test(){}
    Test(Test&& other){}
    Test& operator=(Test&& other) { return *this;}
};

int main()
{
  Test t1;
  Test t2(t1);
}
```

And the error produced by g++ 4.8.1

> ctors.cpp:13:13: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr Test::Test(const Test&)'
>
> Test t2(t1);
>
> ctors.cpp:1:8: note: 'constexpr Test::Test(const Test&)' is implicitly declared as deleted *because 'Test' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator*
>
> struct Test

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks. Please take a look at my question - it is edited. Does this mean, that VC++ compiler produces non-standard code?

Comment: @AlexFarber Correct. FYI g++4.8.1 give me `ctors.cpp:30:15: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr Test::Test(const Test&)' Test t2(t1);`

Comment: @AlexFarber According to the standard it should **not** compile. This is what g++ (see comment above) thinks, and in this case, it is right.

Comment: @AlexFarber I added a simplified example, with the very useful gcc error message (these diagnostics have improved greatly in the last versions of gcc).

Comment: @Alex : VC++ 2010 predates the C++11 standard, so it isn't necessarily "non-conformant", it just implemented early rough-drafts of some features.

Comment: @ildjarn Of course it's non-conformant. An implementation that does not behave as the standard requires is by definition non-conformant. Certainly it's ridiculous to expect a compiler released before the specification to conform to that specification, but that doesn't change the meaning of the term "non-conformant."

Answer (score 1):

According to section 12.8 Copying and moving class objects of the C++ Standard

> 7 If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise,
>   it is defined as defaulted (8.4).
>
> 18 If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class
>   definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator,
>   the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as
>   deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

So in your case and the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator are implicitly declared by the compiler but defined as deleted.