# When will c++11 perform move automatically when std::move is not explicitly used?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, lvalue

If I have a `struct` in which I did not provide any copy and move constructor:

```c++
struct MyStruct {
  MyStruct() { // this is the only function
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

then if I do the following:

```c++
std::vector<MyStruct> vec;
...
vec.push_back(MyStruct());
```

instead of using `std::move()` like the followings:

```c++
vec.push_back(std::move(MyStruct()));
```

Will c++11 smartly do the move for my temporary variable?  Or, how can I make sure it is a move instead of a copy?

Comment: Does `MyStruct` have a move constructor, or not ? It may either be user-declared (explicit) or automatically generated under some conditions (implicit), and of course only movable structures can be moved.

Comment: What @MatthieuM. said. Exactly the point I was trying to make in my answer.

Comment: It still depends :-) It also depends on what you mean by "`std::move` being explicitly used". You should also clarify that.

Comment: Improved the question once again.  Hopefully it looks better now.

Comment: OK, the use of `std::move` makes no difference here. I added that to my answer.

Comment: @keelar: Note: a move constructor may only be generated automatically if each and every attribute can be moved. Not movable types include user-defined types disabling move (whatever the way), references and `const` types for example.

Comment: Not sure if he / she is still here, but to the one who down vote this question: does the updated question address the issues in your mind or look better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11 `std::vector::push_back` will use a move constructor if passed an rvalue (and a move constructor exists for the type), but you should also consider using [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) in such situations; `std::vector::emplace_back` will construct the object in place rather than moving it.

Comment: The struct will have an implicitly defined move constructor if it doesn't define any of the members that suppress it - in a C++11 compliant compiler. Unfortunately, as of yet, in this regard Visual C++ isn't; thus requiring you to explicitly define one.

Comment: +1 recommending `emplace_back` is sound - if post-optimisation an object has to be `move`-d it's still copying many types of data members - it's mainly types with pointers to dynamic memory that become cheap and constant time (but not quite free) to move (e.g. Standard containers).

Comment: As it stands the answer is misleading. For a "move constructor" to be used, the type needs to have one in the first place. It is not simply a matter of passing an rvalue reference.

Comment: It should say "if handed an rvalue". References types of variables, never of expressions.

Comment: @juanchopanza I added a clarification pointing out a move constructor needs to exist for it to be called, which isn't obvious if you're new to move semantics.

Answer (score 7):

> Will c++11 smartly do the move for my temporary variable? Or, how can I make sure it is a move instead of a copy?

It depends. This

```
vec.push_back(MyStruct());
```

will bind to

```
std::vector<MyStruct>::push_back(MyStruct&&);
```

but whether the rvalue passed is moved or copied depends fully on whether `MyStruct` has a move copy constructor (likewise for move assignment).

It will make absolutely no difference if you call

```
vec.push_back(std::move(MyStruct()));
```

because `MyStruct()` is already an rvalue.

So it really depends on the details of `MyStruct`. There is simply not enough information in your question to know if your class has move constructor.

These are the conditions that must be met for a class to have an implicitly generated move constructor:

- no user-declared copy constructors
- no user-declared copy assignment operators
- no user-declared move assignment operators
- no user-declared destructors

Of course, you can always provide your own if any of these conditions are not met:

```
MyStruct(MyStruct&&) = default;
```

Comment: Thanks your answer!  Can you point me to the reference page about the conditions for having an implicitly generated move constructor?

Comment: @keelar I have previously [distilled this from the C++11 standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013430/default-copy-constructor-and-assignment-for-class-with-move-constructor-and-assi), but there is a reference [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor). I haven't cross-checked whether this completely covers what the standard lays out, because there are some confusing corner cases and some details may have changed for C++1y. See also [this and related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174973/when-should-compiler-generate-move-constructor).

Comment: I think the `push_back` call will always bind to `std::vector<MyStruct>::push_back(MyStruct&&);` for an rvalue. However, if no move constructor is available, the construction of the new element in the vector will fall back to the copy ctor inside `push_back` (or become ill-formed if the move ctor is explicitly deleted).

Answer (score 5):

Because the `MyStruct()` will create an rvalue the `T &&` overload will be called.

It's actually very easy to verify ([demo](http://ideone.com/KZA6mv)):

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{ int x; };

void  foo(A &&x){ std::cout<<"&&" <<std::endl; }

void  foo(A &x){ std::cout<<"&" <<std::endl; }

int main() {
    foo(A()); // prints &&
    A a;
    foo(a); // prints &
    return 0;
}
```

---

To clarify: I didn't mention anything about move constructor because one can have an explicitly deleted move constructor and still the `T &&` will be invoked.

E.g ([demo](http://ideone.com/xASGIr)):

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{ int x; A() = default; A(const A& ) = default; A(A&&) = delete; };
/*                                                                  ^
                                                            no move ctor */
void  foo(A &&x){ std::cout<<"&&" <<std::endl; }

void  foo(A &x){ std::cout<<"&" <<std::endl; }

int main() {
    foo(A()); //still prints &&
    A a;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

As I said before this is because it's an rvalue...

Comment: It is not because the overload `A&&` is taken than the move constructor is used (http://ideone.com/JUMBqs)

Comment: Both Q/A are unclear about *moving*, Does that means cast to `T&&` (and there is no need to cast rvalue that way) ? Does it mean move construct/assign ? Any can be used without the other, that is what I want to clarify with my remark.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is going to use [push_back( T&& value )](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), and move the value.

Comment: Not if the type doesn't have a move constructor.

Comment: In which case `std::move` wouldn't help, either. The question is whether `std::move` makes a difference, so that pretty much assumes a move ctor is available.

Comment: @MSalters That is not my interpretation of the question. OP doesn't mention `std::move`, and from other comments, I think they weren't fully aware of when a type is movable.

Comment: @MSalters Ha! I totally missed that. I got used to SO titles having little connection to the question being asked so I must have unconsciously filtered it out.

Answer (score 1):

If the type is movable then it definitely will be. In general standard-complying compiler should always choose move semantics to copy semantics if such are available.

Comment: Thank you.  Can I also know in general which type is movable and which type is not?

Comment: @keelar A type is moveable if it has defined move constructor/move assignment operator. Of course you - as the class - creator has to know whether or not you can perform "destructive copy" on your type or not. Defining (or =default declaring) move member functions is NOT required if your class can have them created by compiler. Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operator.